# a question about preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a question in PHP:

When using **preg_match**, why `#^(([a-z]{2})/)?(([a-z\-]{3,})/(([a-z\-]{3,}))?)?$#i` match `ab/cde/fgh` and do not match `ab/cde`?

(I mean:

```
preg_match_all('#^(([a-z]{2})/)?(([a-z\-]{3,})/(([a-z\-]{3,}))?)?$#i','ab/cde/fgh',$match)

$match =  Array
(
    [0] => ab/cde/fgd
    [1] => ab/
    [2] => ab
    [3] => cde/fgd
    [4] => cde
    [5] => fgd
    [6] => fgd
)
```

and

```
preg_match_all('#^(([a-z]{2})/)?(([a-z\-]{3,})/(([a-z\-]{3,}))?)?$#i','ab/cde',$match)
$match = Array ()
```

Comment: Please improve your question title. We already know it's a question because it's a question, and we already know it's about `preg_match` because it says so in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because as the regex is written, you need a slash after the `cde`. `ab/cde/` should match.

Answer (score 1):

**[a-z-]{3,}** = 3 or more characters